# custom iterator for custom container

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-iterators

I am designing a container that is a grid, represented as a 1D array (templated). I am posting here an extract of the code, there is actually more to it. It is used as a rolling occupancy grid in a robotic application, where each cell represents a small area of the world.

One operation I do frequently with that grid is to go through all the cells and also retrieve their world coordinates:

```
for( unsigned r=0; r<mygrid.rows_; ++r ) {
  for( unsigned c=0; c<mygrid.cols_; ++c ) {
    cell = mygrid.getRC(r,c);
    mygrid.rcToXY(r,c,&x,&y);
  }
}
```

I would like to have an iterator than stores all of these: the cell, its rc coordinates and its xy coordinates.

```
for( Grid<CellType>::const_iterator it=mygrid.begin(); it!=mygrid.end(); ++it ) {
  cell = *it;
  printf("%d %d %f %f\n", it.r(), it.c(), it.x(), it.y());
}
```

Following numerous answers and tutorials online I came up with the following implementation, which works. However it seems a bit clumsy to me, and for academic sake I'd like to make it look better. Also STL compatibility would be great.

```
template <class G, typename C>
class base_iterator
{
private:
  G* grid_;
  C* cell_;
  unsigned r_, c_;  // local
  double  x_, y_;

// this should be private with access for friends (Grid) only
// but I can't make it work
public:
  base_iterator(G* grid, unsigned r, unsigned c) : grid_(grid), r_(r), c_(c)
  {
    cell_ = ( r<grid->rows_ && c<grid->cols_ ) ? &grid_->getRC(r,c) : 0;
    grid_->rcToXY(r,c,&x_,&y_);
  }


public:
  base_iterator() : grid_(0) { }

  // used to cast an iterator to a const_iterator
  template <class G2, typename C2>
  base_iterator(const base_iterator<G2,C2>& other)
  {
    grid_ = other.grid();
    cell_ = & other.cell();
    r_ = other.r();
    c_ = other.c();
    x_ = other.x();
    y_ = other.y();
  }

  // this should be private with access for friends only
  G* grid() const { return grid_; }

  C& cell() { return *cell_; }
  const C& cell() const { return *cell_; }
  unsigned r() const { return r_; }
  unsigned c() const { return c_; }
  double  x() const { return x_; }
  double  y() const { return y_; }

  C* operator->() { return cell_; }
  const C* operator->() const { return cell_; }

  C& operator*() { return *cell_; }
  const C& operator*() const { return *cell_; }

  //prefix
  base_iterator & operator++()
  {
    // my iteration logic here which needs access to grid
    // in order to find the number of rows, etc.
    return *this;
  }

  //postfix
  base_iterator operator++(int)
  {
    base_iterator it(*this);   // make a copy for result
     ++(*this);              // Now use the prefix version to do the work
     return it;          // return the copy (the old) value.
  }

  template <class G2, typename C2>
  bool operator==(const base_iterator<G2,C2> & other) const
  {
    return cell_ == &other.cell();
  }

  template <class G2, typename C2>
  bool operator!=(const base_iterator<G2,C2>& other) const
  { return cell_!=other.cell(); }
};
```

And then in my grid class:

```
  typedef base_iterator<Grid<T>,T> iterator;
  typedef base_iterator<Grid<T> const, T const> const_iterator;

  iterator begin() { return iterator(this,0,0); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(this,rows_,cols_); }

  const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(this,0,0); }
  const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(this,rows_,cols_); }
```

Again, this works, but I feel that it's a bit clumsy (see the comments in the iterator code), and I'd like to know how I can improve it. I saw numerous posts about using boost iterator facade or adaptor, but I could not figure out how to adapt it to my case.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found one solution, that I am quite satisfied with. Here is the full listing for reference. There are some tricky parts that took me some time, in particular in order to be able to take the implementation outside of the class declarations. I haven't managed to make class base_iterator a non-nested class of Grid, according to what I read here and there, I think it's not possible.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>


template <class T>
class Grid
{
public:
  // these should be private, with public getters...
  double resolution_;
  unsigned rows_, cols_;
  int map_r0_, map_c0_; // grid coordinates of origin of map

private:
  T* cell_;

public:
  Grid(double resolution, unsigned rows, unsigned cols);
  ~Grid() { delete[] cell_; }

  T & getRC(unsigned r, unsigned c);
  const T & getRC(unsigned r, unsigned c) const;
  void rcToXY(unsigned r, unsigned c, double* x, double* y) const;

public:
  template <class GridType, class CellType>
  class base_iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, CellType>
  {
  private:
    friend class Grid;
    GridType* grid_;
    CellType* cell_;
    unsigned r_, c_;  // local
    double  x_, y_;

    base_iterator(GridType* grid, unsigned r, unsigned c);

  public:
    base_iterator() : grid_(0) { }

    template <class G2, class C2>
    base_iterator(const base_iterator<G2,C2>& other);

    CellType& cell() { return *cell_; }
    const CellType& cell() const { return *cell_; }
    unsigned r() const { return r_; }
    unsigned c() const { return c_; }
    double  x() const { return x_; }
    double  y() const { return y_; }

    CellType* operator->() { return cell_; }
    const CellType* operator->() const { return cell_; }

    CellType& operator*() { return *cell_; }
    const CellType& operator*() const { return *cell_; }

    //prefix
    base_iterator & operator++();

    //postfix
    base_iterator operator++(int);

    template <class G2, class C2>
    bool operator==(const base_iterator<G2,C2> & other) const
    { return cell_ == other.cell_; }

    template <class G2, class C2>
    bool operator!=(const base_iterator<G2,C2>& other) const
    { return cell_ != other.cell_; }
  };

  typedef base_iterator<Grid<T>,T> iterator;
  typedef base_iterator<Grid<T> const, T const> const_iterator;

  iterator begin() { return iterator(this,0,0); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(this,rows_,0); }

  const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(this,0,0); }
  const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(this,rows_,0); }
};


template <class T>
Grid<T>::Grid(double resolution, unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
  : resolution_(resolution), rows_(rows), cols_(cols), map_r0_(0), map_c0_(0)
{
  cell_ = new T[rows_*cols_];
}

template <class T>
T & Grid<T>::getRC(unsigned r, unsigned c)
{
  if (r >= rows_ || c >= cols_)
    throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds");
  return cell_[r * cols_ + c];
}

template <class T>
const T & Grid<T>::getRC(unsigned r, unsigned c) const
{
  if (r >= rows_ || c >= cols_)
    throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds");
  return cell_[r * cols_ + c];
}

template <class T>
void Grid<T>::rcToXY(unsigned r, unsigned c, double* x, double* y) const
{
  *x = (map_c0_ + c + 0.5) * resolution_;
  *y = (map_r0_ + r + 0.5) * resolution_;
}


template <class T>
template <class GridType, class CellType>
Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType>::base_iterator(GridType* grid, unsigned r, unsigned c)
: grid_(grid), r_(r), c_(c)
{
  if( r<grid->rows_ && c<grid->cols_ ) {
    cell_ = &grid_->getRC(r,c);
    grid_->rcToXY(r,c,&x_,&y_);
  }
  else
    cell_ = &grid_->getRC(grid->rows_-1,grid->cols_-1) + 1;
}

// beautiful triple template declaration !
template <class T>
template <class GridType, class CellType>
template <class G2, class C2>
Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType>::base_iterator(const Grid<T>::base_iterator<G2,C2>& other)
{
  grid_ = other.grid_;
  cell_ = other.cell_;
  r_ = other.r();
  c_ = other.c();
  x_ = other.x();
  y_ = other.y();
}

template <class T>
template <class GridType, class CellType>
Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType> & Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType>::operator++()
{
  assert( grid_!=0 );

  if( c_==grid_->cols_-1 )
  {
    c_ = 0;
    x_ = (grid_->map_c0_ + 0.5) * grid_->resolution_;
    ++r_;
    y_ += grid_->resolution_;
  }
  else
  {
    ++c_;
    x_ += grid_->resolution_;
  }
  ++cell_;

  return *this;
}

template <class T>
template <class GridType, class CellType>
Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType> Grid<T>::base_iterator<GridType,CellType>::operator++(int)
{
  base_iterator it(*this);   // make a copy for result
   ++(*this);              // Now use the prefix version to do the work
   return it;          // return the copy (the old) value.
}

void print(unsigned i)
{
  printf("%d ", i);
}

int main()
{
  Grid<unsigned> mygrid(.1,2,3);
  unsigned ctr=0;
  for( Grid<unsigned>::iterator it=mygrid.begin(); it!=mygrid.end(); ++it )
    *it = ctr++;

  ctr = 0;
  printf("All elements: r, c, x, y, value\n");
  for( Grid<unsigned>::const_iterator it=mygrid.begin(); it!=mygrid.end(); ++it ) {
    assert( *it == ctr++ );
    printf("%d %d %f %f %d\n", it.r(), it.c(), it.x(), it.y(), *it);
  }

  printf("All elements values: ");
  std::for_each(mygrid.begin(), mygrid.end(), print);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```